# angular-tablesorter not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

This is code which I have written for sortable table. I have added ts-wrapper, ts-repeat in the proper place as per given in the example of angular-tableSorter. But this is not working, please help me.

```js
var app = angular.module('emnApp',['ngRoute','anguFixedHeaderTable','angular-tablesorter']);
```

```html
<table id="myTable" fixed-header class="table table-striped tableChck marB0" ts-wrapper>
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableheadPP">
            <th ng-repeat="col in TableColumns" ts-repeat>{{col}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="container tableContainer pad0">
        <tr class="tablerowPP" ng-repeat="history in HistoryTable">
            <td ng-repeat="col in history track by $index" ts-repeat>{{col}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is not working could you please let know in detail ? ,. also could you please add your angular code

Comment: i am not getting a sortable table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put ts-criteria on column header whichever ones you want to do sort on and put ts-default for default sorting.

And remove 'track by $index' . Angular-tablesorter library doesn't seem to work nicely with track by.